# undefined reference to 'some_function'?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, x86-64

I am trying to compile a C++ program and it gives me this error.

```
undefined reference to 'some_function'
```

Whereas I do add the file which contains `some_function` in the makefile. Also I include the declaration of `some_function` in the file where I use it. So why does the compiler still complains that it can't find it? What can be the possible reasons?

My makefile is like that

```
CXX = g++
CXXFILES = dlmalloc.c pthreads.cpp queue.cpp 

CXXFLAGS = -O3 -o prog -rdynamic -D_GNU_SOURCE
LIBS = -lpthread -ldl

all:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFILES) $(LIBS) $(CXXFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f prog *.o
```

`some_function` is defined in `dlmalloc.c` and used inside `pthreads.cpp`. Does it have to do with the fact that `dlmalloc.c` is a C source code file and others are C++ files. Maybe I should use the `extern "C"` keyword with `some_function` here, right?

Comment: You may get more helpful inputs if you can show the compilation command or the Makefile snippet wherein you compile the files

Comment: It probably means you haven't compiled the code containing the function, or you haven't linked it.

Comment: You've tagged the question both C and C++. Are both source files written in the same language?

Comment: Using `extern "C"` seems like a very good idea!

Answer (score 8):

> Maybe I should use the extern "C" keyword here, right?

Yes. If you want to call a function compiled as C from C++ code, then you need to declare it `extern "C"` - but only in C++, since that's not valid syntax in C.

You can use the `__cplusplus` preprocessor symbol to create a header that's valid for either language:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void some_function();

/* many, many more C declarations */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The stuff inside `extern "C" { ... }` is handled as C declarations. Be careful to make sure each function is *always* declared this way for C++, and in the odd chance that the C function is actually written in C++ (**strongly** discouraged!) the decaration *must* come before the actual definition of the function.